# Forms dialog is closed immediately after showing

Tags: c#, .net, forms, dll, showdialog

There is a big complex application, with many .NET and Native DLLs.
`Main_App.exe` is a Windows Forms app. In its `MainForm_Load()`, loads a Native (ATL) COM DLL class, calls into it, which in its `FinalConstruct()` loads and calls via COM into another .NET dll, and that tries to display a Form.

```
public void ShowXXXXDialog()
{
    XXXXDialog dlg = new XXXXDialog();
    dlg.ShowDialog();
}
```

It opens and closes immediately (after ~100 msec) with Cancel result.
My observations so far:

1. If I add a `MsgBox.Show(".....")` BEFORE calling `dlg.ShowDialog()`, works fine.
2. If I call `dlg.ShowDialog();` again (so twice), second time it works fine.
3. If we call `ShowXXXXDialog` after startup finished, it works fine.
4. If I attach to VS to debug, it works fine.
5. If I replace XXXXDialog to another one, same behavior (so not related to XXXXDialog)

Based on these observations, my feeling is that, when `ShowXXXXDialog()` is called during `Main_App.exe` startup, the `MainForm_Load()` is not yet finished and it seems something is not properly initialized in .NET Forms?
So calling `dlg.ShowDialog()` will open&close immediately. However, it probably finishes .NET Forms initialization, as calling `dlg.ShowDialog()` again will work properly for the second call. (or displaying a msgbox will also solve...see point 2))

I put a breakpoint into `XXXXDialog.FormClosing()`, but I don't see anything special. The callstack:

```
*** IMMEDIATELY CLOSED -> AnotherNETLib.dll!AnotherNETLib.AnotherNETLibClass.XXXXDialog.XXXXDialog_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) Line 119 C#
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog(bool closingOnly)   Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FContinueMessageLoop(int reason, int pvLoopData, System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG[] msgPeeked)  Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)   Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)  Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)  Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() Unknown
*** CALLS "dlg.ShowDialog();"   ->      AnotherNETLib.dll!AnotherNETLib.AnotherNETLibClass.ShowXXXXDialog() Line 719    C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
*** CALLS TO A .NET LIB VIA COM -> NativeCOMLib.dll!ATL::CComPtr<IDispatch>::Invoke0(long dispid, tagVARIANT * pvarRet) Line 465    C++
    NativeCOMLib.dll!ATL::CComPtr<IDispatch>::Invoke0(const wchar_t * lpszName, tagVARIANT * pvarRet) Line 475  C++
    NativeCOMLib.dll!CNativeClass::ShowXXXXDialog() Line 204    C++
    NativeCOMLib.dll!CNativeClass::FinalConstruct() Line 130    C++
    NativeCOMLib.dll!ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<CNativeClass> >::CreateInstance(void * pv, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 2009    C++
   NativeCOMLib.dll!ATL::CComCreator2<ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<CNativeClass> >,ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComAggObject<CNativeClass> > >::CreateInstance(void * pv, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 2094 C++
    NativeCOMLib.dll!ATL::CComClassFactory::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppvObj) Line 3738 C++
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark) Line 5430    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic) Line 193 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type) Line 134 C#
*** CALLS TO NATIVE COM -> Main_AppNET.exe!MainApp.Libs.LoadLib(string id) Line 71  C#
    Main_AppNET.exe!MainApp.MainForm.MainForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 654  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    Main_AppNET.exe!MainApp.MainForm.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 637   C#
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
   Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinTabbedMdi.v9.2.dll!Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabbedMdi.MdiParentSubclasser.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@24()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!7a6190d0()  Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(bool value)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Visible.set(bool value)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown
***APP STARTUP -> Main_AppNET.exe!MainApp.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 127  C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    mscoreei.dll!__CorExeMain@0()   Unknown
    mscoree.dll!_ShellShim__CorExeMain@0()  Unknown
    mscoree.dll!__CorExeMain_Exported@0()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

You can see in it, .NET startup -> Native call -> .NET lib call -> Open form -> Close form.

So far, I have no idea why it is doing this, so I made a nasty workaround, with stopwatch, measure the time of `dlg.ShowDialog()`, and if return <1sec, I expect the above issue, and call it again. It works...but I am curious what is going on?

Comment: There are no hints here, other than the notable bad practice of preventing the main window from getting visible and the dialog having a pretty hard time finding a decent owner.  Use the debugger to find how the form's DialogResult property got assigned.  Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function and type "System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_DialogResult".   When it breaks the Stack Trace tells the tale.  You might for example discover it picked the wrong owner.

Comment: @HansPassant good idea, but see my point 4: if I attach VS, the issue is NOT present, then dialog is not closed at first call. Besides that, I tried to pass the MainForm as owner in XXXXDialog constructor, but same behavior.

Comment: One comment, the title is misleading, it's not related to VS2008 -> VS2015 change, but in VS2008 version a splash screen was displayed before the dialog, which "toggled" the good behavior (just as a msgbox or anything, see point 1 or 2). Now I fixed it in VS2015, and with splash screen it also works the same "proper way". So dialog is not closed automatically now. Root cause is unknown (although I am very-very curious), but now issue is not happening anymore. Strange. I removed any VS 2008/2015 related text from the question.